# Rails - 2 forms one model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm struggling with this one, basically I want two forms to submit to the one model.  When the first form is complete, the second one is rendered which will contain the remaining information which the model requires. Ideally I would like to combine the two returned hashes and save them together at once. If there is a more sensible way of doing this please let me know. Thanks in advance.

app/controllers/books_controller.rb

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @book = @library.books.build
    @user = current_user
  end

  def create
    @book = @library.books.build(params[:book])

    if @book.total_pages.nil?
       @book_first_page = @book
       render 'new'
    else
      @book.update_attributes(@book_first_page)

    if @book.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

app/views/books/new.html.erb

```
<% if @book.title.nil?  %>
<%= form_for [:library, @book] do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

<div class="form-group input-group-sm">
  <%= f.label :title, 'What is the title of the book?' %>
  <%= f.text_area :title, class: "form-control" %>
</div>

<%= f.submit "Submit Title", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
<% else %>
<%= form_for [:library, @book] do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

<div class="form-group input-group-sm">
  <%= f.label :total_pages, "How many pages?:" %>
  <%= f.text_field :total_pages, class: "form-control" %>
</div>
<%= f.submit "Submit Number of Pages", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might also use a single form for all your data, but initially showing only the first portion of the form, and then employ javascript to hide the first part and show the second part when the first part is complete.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

For example, see http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

Answer (score 0):

why you need to update in two form. use just one form

Comment: I agree it would be easier to use just the one form, but according to the design of the site, there should be two forms one leading on to the other....